# What could be better SQL statement than this?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having

Two tables P, W are connected by Group foreign key. The bellow inner SQL returns only the table P 'names' which has only one matching 'type' in W table. The outer SQL displays name and type column values.

Basically i need to retrieve only the names(p) who has only one type (W).

The bellow statement is correct, however, i wonder if i can do it without inner SQL or any other better solution.

```
select p.name, w.type
from p, w
where p.name in
(
    select p.name
    from P , w 
    where p.group = w.group
    group by p.name
    having count(w.type) = 1
)
AND 
p.group= w.group
```

Comment: "i wonder if i can do it without inner SQL" Short answer No not possible because you need w.type also and you group by on p.name.. That requires a inner query like this or a join te get the correct data for w.type.

Comment: Another idea would be to create a View for the inner query and then you can SELECT FROM that View.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondNijland, i thought the same, but may be some one has better solution

Comment: You could start to use better join syntax. Stop using the where clause for joins.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one type, it is also always the maximum (and minimum) value. So you can simplify the retrieval of this value without an outer query:

```
select p.name, max(w.type) as type
from p
join w on p.group = w.group
group by p.name
having count(w.type) = 1
```

In `1:n`-relations (e.g. one name belongs to only one group, which you have here since `name` is the primary key), you usually just need to `group by` in `w`; this will simplify your inner query a bit less (it saves one join compared to your original query), but is more generalizable (e.g. to different counts):

```
select p.name, w.type
from p, w
where p.group in
(
    select w.group
    from w 
    group by w.group
    having count(w.type) = 1
)
AND 
p.group= w.group
```

Comment: This is probably the answer the OP is looking for - however the question is phrased so badly it could be completely wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Column 'name' is primary key in table P, not 'group'. A 'group; can be associated with many 'types'. ie, table W can have multiple combinations of 'group + type'. My requirement is to get a 'name' who has single 'group + type'. Columns name(primary key) and group are in table P. Columns group and type are in table W. I hope i explained better here

Comment: @SBT Thanks for the clarification about the primary key, I removed the uncertainty about the name being unique from the answer. As long as `name` is unique and has only one group (which is the case), the code should work and should return the same result than your query.